# Draw clickable rectangles and I do not know how set params before onDraw method

Tags: java, android, ondraw, onclicklistener

I am trying to make clickable rectangles. I've looked around and I created quite good code :)

I create constructor of my own rectangle class, then i set some values of it.
However, onDraw method looks like creates and draw rectangle but without constructor's new variables' values.
What do I do wrong?

This is default MyActivity class:

```
ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
List<MiniRectangle> miniRectangleList = new ArrayList<MiniRectangle>();

for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    int numberRandom = r.nextInt(3);

    MiniRectangle miniRectangle = new MiniRectangle(this);
    miniRectangle.set_color(colors.get(numberRandom));
    miniRectangle.set_size(50);
    miniRectangle.set_id_color(numberRandom);
    miniRectangle.set_number(i);

    ll.addView(miniRectangle);

    miniRectangleList.add(miniRectangle);
}

setContentView(ll);
```

This is my own rectangle class

```
public class MiniRectangle extends View implements View.OnClickListener {

    Context context;
    int _size;
    int _color;
    int _id_color;
    int _number;

    public MiniRectangle(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        System.out.println(get_number());
        Toast.makeText(context, get_number(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(get_color());
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);

        int kleft = (get_number() % 8) * get_size();
        int kright = kleft + get_size() - 2;

        int ktop = 1 * get_size();
        int kbottom = ktop + get_size() - 2;

        canvas.drawRect(kleft, ktop, kright, kbottom, paint);
    }
}
```

I can say that after run project I get only one rectangle. No wonder if every rectangle has the same position. Please Help.

---

The result should shows chess of clickable rectangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
ll.addView(miniRectangle, new LayoutParams(50, 50));
```

with you own parameters for [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) instead of

```
ll.addView(miniRectangle);
```

and start in onDraw() with

```
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, get_size(), get_size(), paint);
```

with respect to your LayoutParams values.

Comment: no, i would like to put that rectangles horizontal, and add another row of rectangles. It should look like a chess with clickable rectangles..

Comment: a simple LinearLayout won't work then. try put your rectangles in horizontal layouts, which should be put into the vertical linear layout.

or you start with a relative layout.